# JPA - how to replicate update versioned query of Hibernate in openjpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, openjpa

I'm trying to replicate the behavior of **"update versioned"** of Hibernate in Openjpa:

```
em.createQuery("update versioned MyEntity m set m.otherEntity=null where m.otherEntity=:otherEntity).setParameter("otherEntity", otherEntity).executeUpdate();
```

I tried the same query in openjpa but i'm getting a error for this query  (it takes the "versioned" as a alias), so its clearly a HQL feature.

Comment: clearly that is invalid JPQL so what do you expect? `UPDATE entity_name [[AS] identification_variable] SET update_item {, update_item}* WHERE ...`

Comment: I'm expecting an answer and not mentioning what I already figured out by myself and wrote it in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate spec:

> In keeping with the EJB3 specification, HQL UPDATE statements, by default, do not effect the version or the timestamp property values for the affected entities. However, you can force Hibernate to reset the version or timestamp property values through the use of a versioned update. This is achieved by adding the VERSIONED keyword after the UPDATE keyword.

so HQL has the option to use the **update versioned** to reset version
however in OpenJpa:

> Bulk update maps directly to a database update operation, bypassing optimistic locking checks. Portable applications must manually update the value of the version column, if desired, and/or manually validate the value of the version column.